# PNG image wrongfully opened as RGB by pil.image

Tags: python, png, python-imaging-library

I have images like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jyGp.png), which I believe have 4 data channels (RGB + an alpha channel).

When I try to open this image like so, I can't access the transparency layer.

```
from PIL import Image
fn = 'FUgqUA5.png'
im = Image.open(fn)
im.mode # returns RGB instead of desired .png
im.getData()[0] # returns (0,0,0) instead of desired (0,0,0,255)
```

How do I open this image as an actual `.png`? Is it possible the image is saved as a 3-channel `png` instead and that this image simply doesn't have a 4th channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saved the image and saw the properties via image editor and it did not mention that there is a 4th channel. 
PS: (image editor is [ImageMagick](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick6))

[image: image properties]

Comment: Then I'll have to assume the `png` was wrongfully saved before I received it. Thanks